# How do combine tables and views?

Tags: sql

How do you combine tables and views into one query? I have two Select statements one is inner join already I would like to combine the table and views in the second select and make one query.

```
SELECT PROJECT.PROJ_ID,
       PROJECT.HULL_NUM_ID,
       PROJECT.SHIP_TYPE_CD,
       PROJECT.PROJ_NM,
       ICP_SUMMARY.MOD_STOP_DT
  FROM BAIM.ICP_SUMMARY ICP_SUMMARY
 INNER JOIN BAIM.PROJECT PROJECT
    ON ICP_SUMMARY.PROJ_ID = PROJECT.PROJ_ID

SELECT ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.PROJ_ID,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.LBR_EST_MANDAYS,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.LBR_ICP_MANDAYS,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.MATL_EST_COST,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.MATL_ICP_COST,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.TOTAL_EST_COST,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.TOTAL_ICP
  FROM BAIM.ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW
```

Comment: You can join tables and views together by using joins as long as there are related keys to join on.   What problem are you having?

Answer (score 2):

You treat views just like you would a table.  You can perform joins on views, and you can have as many views as you need in the select statement.

Comment: You showed two queries, but didn't specify ***how*** you want them joined, or I'd have included the necessary SQL statement.  However, since it looks like you already know how to do joins, I suspect that you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: I need to inner join them but not sure how.

Comment: The table and view both have a `PROJ_ID`, why can't you join on that? It's just like joining on a table.

Comment: Here is what I got so far SELECT PROJECT.PROJ_ID,
       PROJECT.HULL_NUM_ID,
       PROJECT.SHIP_TYPE_CD,
       PROJECT.PROJ_NM,
       ICP_SUMMARY.MOD_STOP_DT
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.PROJ_ID,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.LBR_EST_MANDAYS,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.LBR_ICP_MANDAYS,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.MATL_EST_COST,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.MATL_ICP_COST,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.TOTAL_EST_COST,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.TOTAL_ICP
FROM BAIM.ICP_SUMMARY ICP_SUMMARY ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW

Comment: @user1555520: add your code to your question (pick 'edit'), don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `JOIN` on the table and the view, similar to this:

```
SELECT PROJECT.PROJ_ID,
       PROJECT.HULL_NUM_ID,
       PROJECT.SHIP_TYPE_CD,
       PROJECT.PROJ_NM,
       ICP_SUMMARY.MOD_STOP_DT,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.PROJ_ID,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.LBR_EST_MANDAYS,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.LBR_ICP_MANDAYS,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.MATL_EST_COST,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.MATL_ICP_COST,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.TOTAL_EST_COST,
       ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.TOTAL_ICP
  FROM BAIM.ICP_SUMMARY ICP_SUMMARY
 INNER JOIN BAIM.PROJECT PROJECT
    ON ICP_SUMMARY.PROJ_ID = PROJECT.PROJ_ID
 INNER JOIN BAIM.ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW -- do JOIN Here
    ON ICP_SUMMARY.PROJ_ID = ICP_SUMMARY_JS_VW.PROJ_ID -- select the field to JOIN on
```